# I get Fond nil error when calling a function from viewDidDisappear but not from button Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a behaviour that I don't understand. I have two animation functions `cartItemAnimation()`and `cartItemAnimationHide()`. If I call the functions from `ShopViewController`'s buttons they work as expected, but if I call `cartItemAnimation()`from returning to `ShopViewController`from `ItemsDisplayViewController`'s `viewDidDisapper()`I get a `Found nil`error.
`cartItemAnimationHide()`is called from `ShopViewController`'s `viewWillAppear()`.
Basically is an animation that hides a small `imageView` when loading `ShopViewController`and than it shows it when returning to it after dismissing `ItemsDisplayViewController`.

Here are the involved functions:

ShopViewController's functions:

```
func cartItemAnimation() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.9, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.itemAnimationImage.transform = .identity  // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil ..
        }) { (success) in
//            self.itemAnimationImage.alpha = 0
        }

    }

    func cartItemAnimationHide() {
//        self.itemAnimationImage.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.itemAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: -265 , y: -667)
        }) { (success) in
            self.itemAnimationImage.alpha = 1
        }

    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(false)
        if ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter ?? 0 <= 0 {
            cartItemAnimationHide()
        }
    }
```

ItemsDisplayViewController's function :

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        if ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter ?? 0 > 0 {
            let vc = ShopViewController()
            vc.cartItemAnimation()
            ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter = 0
        }
    }
```

`ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter`is just a counter that I use for dismissing view controllers in cascade.

Can you see why I get this error on `self.itemAnimationImage.transform = .identity`line, but it works perfectly if I call the functions from buttons?
As usual many thanks.

Comment: What's the link between your controllers? Are they stacked in a NavigationController?

Comment: @Y.Bonafons yes they are in a NavigationController, I use present Modally segue, so to go back to `ShopViewController`i dismiss `ItemsDisplayViewController` . Can it be the reason for this error?

Comment: So if ItemDisplayController is presented as a modal, you still have your ShopViewController "behind". So you dont have to create it again.

Comment: Try `viewWillDisappear` instead of `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: @Y.Bonafons yes, it's still behind, why do you say I recreate it?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon did try 'viewWillDisappear`but I get the same nil error..

Comment: I said that because of this line: let vc = ShopViewController()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you present your ItemsDisplayViewController as a Modal, you can add a pointer to your ShopViewController

```
class ItemsDisplayViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var shopController: ShopViewController?
    ...

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        if ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter ?? 0 > 0 {
            shopController?.cartItemAnimation()
            ShopGlobalVariables.dismissCounter = 0
        }
    }
}
```

And dont forget to set the reference to shopController in the ShopViewController probably:

```
class ShopViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let itemController = segue.destination as? ItemDisplayViewController {
            itemController.shopController = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, instead of instantiate it as `vc = ShopViewController` right?

Comment: I just tried it, and I didn't  get the error now, but it didn't call the function either ..then I realized I did miss a line in my `prepare(for segue:) `and it was `vc.shopController = self` in my case. And now its working as due.
I didn't know this whole VC pointer concept. Can you point me to an explanation of it please? I'd like to understand it.
Many thank for helping so quickly guys.

Comment: What you did was creating a new instance of the ShopController (let vc = `ShopViewController()`) but what you wanted was applied the animation on an existing controller (the one which presenting the modal). And this one was still in view hierarchy, so you can call `cartItemAnimation()` on it. And because you are using segue, the way to achieve dependency injection is to use the `prepare()` function. Hope its more clear :)